# SQL-Query using Pivot when Fields Are not fix

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

**Before Using Pivot Function in SQL I am getting This  record structure**

[image]

**After Using Pivot :**

[image]

**Here is My SQL Query**

```
SELECT

            FromHubID,
            FromHubName,
            ToHubID,
            SUM([1 - 100]) AS [1 - 100],
            SUM([101 - 250]) AS [101 - 250],
            SUM([251 - 500]) AS [251 - 500],
            SUM([501 - 1000]) AS [501 - 1000]

            FROM
    (SELECT 
            AccountGroupID,
            FromHubID,
            FromHubName,
            ToHubID,
            T_ID,
            [1 - 100],
            [101 - 250],
            [251 - 500],
            [501 - 1000]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
              AG.AccountGroupID
             ,AG.FromHubID
             ,FH.Hub_Name AS FromHubName
             ,AG.ToHubID
             ,AG.T_ID
             ,CONVERT(VARCHAR , [MinWeight])  + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR ,[MaxWeight]) AS slot
             ,[Rate]

          FROM 
                [CourierDev].[dbo].[AccountGroupQuotation] AS AG
                INNER JOIN HubMaster AS FH ON FH.Hub_Id = AG.FromHubID
          WHERE
                 accountgroupid = 1

    )Sourcetable

    PIVOT
    (
           Sum(Rate)          
           FOR slot IN (  [1 - 100],
                        [101 - 250],
                        [251 - 500],
                        [501 - 1000] )
    )AS AGQuotationList 
    )AS tbl

     GROUP  BY 
            FromHubID,
            FromHubName,
            ToHubID
```

My problem is The number of Fields in slot And Value of It is not fix here i Add static Field in Pivot Syntax and select Syntax 
For this particular record but how to manage when value of slot and count of slot value is not fix?

**FOR Example** 
If there is only 2 Types of records [1 - 100],[101 - 250] then i want two pivot for that only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max),
        @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns,'') +','+QUOTENAME(slot)
FROM #YourTable
GROUP BY slot

SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT  FromHubID,
        FromHubName,
        ToHubID
        '+@columns+'
FROM #YourTable
PIVOT (
    SUM(Rate) FOR slot IN ('+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+')
) as pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Output:

```
FromHubID   FromHubName     ToHubID 1 - 100 101 - 250   251 - 500   501 - 1000
5           BARODA R. O.    1       1       2           3           4
5           BARODA R. O.    5       5       6           7           8
```

Comment: Here Slot is concatination of 2 feild So i used QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR , [MinWeight])  + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR ,[MaxWeight]))     and GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR , [MinWeight])  + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR ,[MaxWeight])   it is working here  BUT When i use  '+@columns+' As slot and  SUM(Rate) FOR slot IN ('+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+')  It gives Error Invalid Column 'slot'   How to solve this?

Comment: The simple way is to put what you get before pivoting in some temp table, then use the code I provided.